# JQuery browser compatability issues with sorting divs

Tags: jquery, sorting, cross-browser

I'm trying to make a search/sort feature for my site and everything works 110% on FF. On chrome everything works except dualSort, in which it only sorts by the H4 content and not by the price, and in IE/Edge it deletes all children of tBox when sorting.

```js
function sortAscend() {
  var sortAscend = $('.tBox').sort(function(a, b) {
    return (parseFloat($(a).find(".tPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')) > parseFloat($(b).find(".tPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')) ? 1 : -1);
  });
  $("#DB").html('').append(sortAscend);
}

function sortDesc() {
  var sortDesc = $('.tBox').sort(function(a, b) {
    return (parseFloat($(a).find(".tPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')) < parseFloat($(b).find(".tPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')) ? 1 : -1);
  });
  $("#DB").html('').append(sortDesc);
}

function dualSort() {
  var yearSort = $('.tBox').sort(function(a, b) {
    var $year1 = parseFloat($(a).find("H4").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    var $year2 = parseFloat($(b).find("H4").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    var $price1 = parseFloat($(a).find(".tPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    var $price2 = parseFloat($(b).find(".tPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    if ($year1 === $year2) {
      return (($year1 > $year2) ? -1 : ($price1 < $price2) ? 1 : 0);
    } else {
      return ($year1 > $year2 ? 1 : -1);
    }
  });
  $("#DB").html('').append(yearSort);
}
```

```html
<div id="DB">
 <div class="tBox">
   <H4>5 Bottles</H4>
   <div class="tPrice">$12.95</div>
 </div>
 <div class="tBox">
   <H4>10 Bottles</H4>
   <div class="tPrice">$15.95</div>
 </div>
 <div class="tBox">
   <H4>10 Bottles</H4>
   <div class="tPrice">$19.95</div>
 </div>
 <div class="tBox">
   <H4>3 Bottles</H4>
   <div class="tPrice">$7.95</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
 parseFloat($(a).find(".tPrice").text(), 10) > parseFloat($(b).find(".tPrice").text(), 10) ? 1 : -1);});
```

and:

```
$('#DB').html(sortAscend);
```

And several plugins that did not work, but what I have currently is the only thing that has worked outside of FF.

Any advice or help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of jQuery? I tried 3.3.1 with Chrome and it appeared to work.

Comment: Updated to try but, chrome still doesn't recognize the price variable when sorting by H4. And nothing changed with IE.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't recognize the price variable"? Are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: Works for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qpfjw082/2/ in both Chrome and Edge (the latter tested using BrowserStack, since I'm on a Mac).

Comment: Why do you have `($year1 > $year2) ?` inside `if ($year1 === $year2)`? It can't be greater since it's equal.

Comment: You're supposed to return `-1` when the second value is less than the first value, not `0`.

Comment: @Barmar jsfiddle is not supported in IE so I cannot verify, However the fiddle still doesn't work on chrome for me. It arranges by H4, but not H4 by price. 
as for `($year1 > $year2) ?` , the example I had found for jQuery dual variable sort used that language. Can you please show me an example that does not use that language and still sorts the correct direction by price? I am not getting an error message, it isn't recognizing that part of code in the end result where it does in FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning the correct value from the comparison function. You're supposed to return a negative number when `$price1 > $price2`, but you're returning `0`.

I think you meant the `$year1 > $year2` test to be `$price1 > $price2`. But you can simplify all of that by using subtraction instead of multiple comparisons.

It's also a good idea to `clone()` the elements. What may be happening when everything disappears is that `$("#DB").html('')` is destroying all the elements within it.

```js
function sortAscend() {
  var sortAscend = $('.tBox').clone().sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat($(a).find(".tPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')) - parseFloat($(b).find(".tPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
  });
  $("#DB").html('').append(sortAscend);
}

function sortDesc() {
  var sortDesc = $('.tBox').clone().sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat($(b).find(".tPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')) - parseFloat($(a).find(".tPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
  });
  $("#DB").html('').append(sortDesc);
}

function dualSort() {
  var yearSort = $('.tBox').clone().sort(function(a, b) {
    var $year1 = parseFloat($(a).find("H4").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    var $year2 = parseFloat($(b).find("H4").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    var $price1 = parseFloat($(a).find(".tPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    var $price2 = parseFloat($(b).find(".tPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    return $year1 === $year2 ? $price1 - $price2 : $year1 - $year2;
  });
  $("#DB").html('').append(yearSort);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="sortAscend()">Price Ascending</button>
<button onclick="sortDesc()">Price Decending</button>
<button onclick="dualSort()">Quantity and Price</button>

<div id="DB">
  <div class="tBox">
    <H4>5 Bottles</H4>
    <div class="tPrice">$12.95</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tBox">
    <H4>10 Bottles</H4>
    <div class="tPrice">$15.95</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tBox">
    <H4>10 Bottles</H4>
    <div class="tPrice">$19.95</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tBox">
    <H4>3 Bottles</H4>
    <div class="tPrice">$7.95</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is wonderful and fixed my problem in chrome, but it still deletes all children of tBox in IE.

Comment: Since I don't have IE I can't debug that.

Comment: Try sorting `$(".tBox").get()` or `$(".tBox").clone(true)`

Comment: Clone did it! Thank you!

Comment: I've added my speculation on why that's needed to the answer, and updated the code.